# Different TextView height when not all lines have content

Tags: android, textview, measure

I have a TextView with lines = 2. I get a different result in the height of the TextView if I set a short text and only 1 line shows up, or I set a longer text and 2 lines show up. This seems to be an issue with the onMeasure function of TextView. In the code I can see that first the height of the Layout is calculated, and then a line height is added for each blank line. Javadoc notes the following:

> Note that markup within the text can cause individual lines to be taller or shorter than this height, and the layout may contain additional first-or last-line padding.

These TextViews are used in a horizontal RecyclerView where I need each list item to be the same height, that's why I set the lines fixed to 2. But apparently that doesn't make it the same height. How can this be fixed?

Some extra info regarding the TextView:

- Font: Helvetica Neue Lt Std Bold
- Text size: 18 sp
- Lineheight: 32 sp

Either it has something to do with the lineheight not being used in the calculation of getLineHeight or Layout. Or something with the font itself. Edit: it's definitely something with the font because lineheight + roboto doesn't create this issue.

Here you can see the difference in height:
[image]

And here the TextViews have the same height because they all have the same number of lines.
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that not more people have run into this. Did you find any additional info about or solution to this?

Comment: @fweigl No, unfortunately not. I haven't been able to fix this yet. I haven't seen this in other apps either, because I've only used this font once.